# Why is inline middleware executed after build-in middleware in .Net Core, regardless of the order they're called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

In a blank ASP.net Core web application, I simplified my Configure() method as such:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            // First Middleware
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
              await next();
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

But when I debug, the UseStaticFile() middleware is called before the code in the inline middleware, even though the inline middleware appears first in code.

Why is this?

Comment: this is a wrong assumption, how exactly did you test it?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on app.UseStaticFiles() and await next();

Comment: You can refer to the [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and see the picture showing the pipeline.

Comment: @bperniciaro no, that way is wrong. the `UseStaticFiles` is run at the time registering the static files middleware. But the `next()` is run at the time processing the request. They're different.

Comment: You're not comparing like for like. `app.Use` is called first, then `app.UseStaticFiles` is called next. Then, when a request is being processed, your `(context, next) =>` lambda method is called before the middleware registered by `UseStaticFiles`.

Comment: @Llama I understand, thank you.